# How to convert references into instances during JSON deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, class-hierarchy

This was a question, but it has been solved. I was trying to do deserialize some JSON data into Java POJO's. For example take the following JSON data:

For the `Account` data i have the following JSON data which refers to users by their id:

```json
{
  "name" : "Bob's Account",
  "roles": {
    "administrator" : "user-1",
    "owner"         : "user-1",
    "participant"   : "user-2" 
  }
}
```

And for the `User`s 'Bob' and 'Alice' i've got this JSON data:

```json
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "id"  : "user-1"
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "id"  : "user-2"
}
```

What i'd wanted to achieve is to deserialize the data into the following Java classes:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Account {
  String name;
  Map<String, User> roles = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and

```java
public class User {
  String id;
  String name;
}
```

Notice that the `Account` class has a map that links `String` to a `User` instance.

Comment: please add the code you use to deserialize the json input. are you using correct method readValue? i think your annotation should have converter=... and not contentConverter=...

Comment: Hi @TomElias, i've added it and figured my error out. The example i gave in my question was a simplified version of my actual code and as it turns out, i had another property for which a similar converter was needed. But i wanted to implement one at a time... Thanks for your support and sorry Internet

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept it or delete the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias, consider it done

Answer (score 1):

To do this you must annotate the property `roles` in the the `Account` object as follows:

```java
  ⋯snip⋯
  @JsonDeserialize(contentConverter = UserReferenceConverter.class)
  Map<String, User> roles = new HashMap<>();
  ⋯snip⋯
```

And then with create a `UserReferenceConverter` that can convert a user-id in the form of a `String` into an actual `User` instance`enter code here`:

```java
public class UserReferenceConverter extends StdConverter<String, User> {
  
  @Override
  public User convert( String value ) {
    // Get the user...
    return UserRepository.getUserById( value );
  }
}
```

To load the `Account` from a JSON string run this:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

  ⋯snip⋯
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Account account = mapper.readValue(json, Account.class);
  ⋯snip⋯
```